# Click event based on eq() selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to fire a click event based on an element I get using `eq()`.

I have three elements with the same class name: `ag-list-item`.

```
<!-- item one -->
<div ag-repeat="" class="ag-list-item ag-not-dragging">
    <span>
        <span class="ag-visible-icons">
        </span>

        <span>Avg. Yield (bu/ac)</span>
    </span>
</div>
<!-- /item one -->

<!-- item two -->
<div ag-repeat="" class="ag-list-item ag-not-dragging">
    <span>
        <span class="ag-visible-icons">
        </span>

        <span>Total Average</span>
    </span>
</div>
<!-- /item two -->

<!-- item three -->
<div ag-repeat="" class="ag-list-item ag-not-dragging">
    <span>
        <span class="ag-visible-icons">
        </span>

        <span>Crop Type</span>
    </span>
</div>
<!-- /item three -->
```

I'm trying to fire a click event on the nested span element of a specific `ag-list-item` element. I've used `:first`to click the first, but would like to target at a specific index (i.e. first, second, third, etc.)

```
// click all with .ag-list-item class
$('.ag-list-item span span').click()

// click first item in set
$('.ag-list-item:first span span').click()

// try to only click the second item in the set

// get second
var el = $('.ag-list-item').children('span span').eq(2);

// click second item in set
$(el).click();
```

Please help!

Comment: Your issue is not clear here. Is the code `$(el).click();` not working for you? Could you please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Might you want `$('.ag-list-item').eq(2).children('span span')`?

Comment: FWIW; `.eq()` constructs a new jQuery object, so there is no need to wrap `el`, it is already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

`.eq(2)` is going to give you the third item, since indexes in this (and most of the computer programming world) are zero-based. You probably want `.eq(1)`.

Also, the purpose of `.eq()` is to avoid needing to re-wrap the result in a jQuery object again.

And I'm guessing, looking at this, that you're looking for the "second" list-item, and you want all the spans inside of that to get the click handler?

```
// get second
var $el = $('.ag-list-item').eq(1);

// click second item in set
$el.children('span span').click();
```